# How could i make the values in my handleChange a new selector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I made a selector that grabs an array of states and then a handleChange function that console. logs the Citys that correspond to the state. Is there a way I can make a new selector From the data from my handleChange.

```
I made a sandbox with my data and what happens when you select a State.
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-montalcini-ttz0j?file=/src/components/CityPicker/CityPicker.jsx

```
const CityPicker = ({ handleCityChange }) => {
  const [cityData, setCity] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setCity(await fetchCity());
    };

    fetchAPI();
  }, []);

  let city = cityData.map(county => county.county);
  let state = cityData.map(province => province.province);

  const uniqueStates = state.filter(
    (val, id, array) => array.indexOf(val) === id
  );
  const uniqueCity = city.filter((val, id, array) => array.indexOf(val) === id);

  const handleChange = function(state) {
    const result = cityData
      .filter(entry => entry.province === state)
      .map(entry => entry.county);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  };

  return (
    <FormControl className={styles.formControl}>
      <NativeSelect
        defaultValue=" "
        onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="">States</option>
        {uniqueStates.map((uniqueStates, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={uniqueStates}>
            {uniqueStates}
          </option>
        ))}
      </NativeSelect>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default CityPicker;
```

Comment: Could you copy your code into the question instead of just having it in an external link? Having the code in the question makes it easier for others with the same question to find it.

Comment: Ok i put the code to the component i am using

Answer (score 0):

Since the cities will be used to render content in your component, they should be set as state in your component. Add another `useState`, and instead of doing a console.log, set the state with the data. Then update your render logic to consume that state.

```
const CityPicker = ({ handleCityChange }) => {
  const [allCities, setAllCities] = useState([]);
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const [counties, setCounties] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      const cities = await fetchCity();
      setAllCities(cities);
      setStates([...new Set(cities.map(city => city.province))]);
    };

    fetchAPI();
  }, []);

  function handleSelectState = function(state) {
    setCounties([
      ...new Set(allCities
        .filter(city => city.province === state)
        .map(city => city.county)
      )
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl className={styles.formControl}>
      <NativeSelect
        defaultValue=" "
        onChange={e => handleSelectState(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="">States</option>
        {states.map((state, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={state}>
            {state}
          </option>
        ))}
      </NativeSelect>
      { counties && 
        <NativeSelect defaultValue=" ">
          <option value="">States</option>
          {counties.map((county, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={county}>
              {county}
            </option>
          ))}
        </NativeSelect>
      }
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default CityPicker;
```